# MongoDB couldn't start because have error

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu

I recently installed mongodb on my vps, but it returned an error for me:

> Jan 31 01:35:47 servidor-1 mongod[6960]: Error reading config file: No
>   such file or directory    Jan 31 01:35:47 servidor-1 mongod[6960]: try
>   '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information

[service mongodb status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjsJq.png)

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does `/etc/mongod.conf` exist?

Comment: /etc/mongod.conf no, but /etc/mongodb.conf yes

Comment: Your server is looking for a `mongod.conf` though, not sure if it was supposed to be created by you or provided though the installation.

Comment: I reinstalled and the etc/mongod.conf now exists, but this error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do check or create this file.

> /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service

It specifies the location of the configuration file. It should either be `/etc/mongodb.conf` or `/etc/mongod.conf` depending on your machine.

```
#Unit contains the dependencies to be satisfied before the service is started.
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
# Service tells systemd, how the service should be started.
# Key `User` specifies that the server will run under the mongodb user and
# `ExecStart` defines the startup command for MongoDB server.
[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf
# Install tells systemd when the service should be automatically started.
# `multi-user.target` means the server will be automatically started during boot.
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After this run basic commands to check.

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb.service
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl stop mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```